# Create custom event with custom params

Tags: firebase, events, parameters, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to to create a new audience group for users who spent more than 1 hour on my android app.
So as far as I know I should create a custom event "time spent" that collect how much time users are spent.

Should I create a condition in my event/parameter to customize time spent to be > 1 hour?

Is there anything wrong or step I missed to achieve my purpose?

Is this code correct?

```java
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("time_duration", time);
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("time-spent", params);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events may not be a good way to track user's time spent because time spent is an accumulation while events should be a point in time. I'd suggest to define an audience on the user engagement which is automatically tracked, or you can set user property at interval time. For example, you can log a cumulative time at every hour or every day, and then define an audience filter on that particular user property.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Do you mean by your first suggestion to create new audience group and to use "user_engagement" event to filter that audience?

Comment: Yes, you can read more about it at https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/12/new-changes-sessions-user-engagement.html under the section "What's changing with user engagement?" for more information

Comment: Thanks a lot, one last question: user_ engagement event is not listed with the built in events or recommended events in my firebase console, should i just log user_ engagement event and it will work as expected or is there something wrong with my console?

Comment: Have you tried choosing the Suggested Audiences --> General --> Recently Active Users yet? You can try to log your own custom user engagement events but there are some edge cases that you need to do on your own.